# Ubuntu recognize the secondary monitor but it has "no signal"

Tags: display

My ubuntu recognizes correctly both of my screens, but for some reason, the secondary one (Samsung) has "no signal" message.
How can that be resolved, what more information can I provide?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to click the apply button after your last change?

Comment: @MongrelShark - I was just playing around with this... its not that

Comment: Has the Samsung monitor multiple inputs? If so, you may have to select the input you are actually using.

Comment: @SexyMF the monitor itself has a switch or button to select the input, if your Samsung monitor has indeed multiple inputs. Check the Samsung user manual for this.

Comment: Having the same issue. I just got a new laptop (Dell G3 15) and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Previous one was working perfectly with the same monitor. Dell Inspiron 15 7559 with Ubuntu 16.04